# Mutable structs as member variables for performance in Serialization/JSON Generation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, struct

I tried to read up why mutable structs are evil, which was previously posted here.

[Why are mutable structs “evil”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil)

But my post is more about a specific scenario.

Given following scenario

I want to have a small, fast to serialize "data class", to speed up my Save/Load Mechanism

I have a Player class which I can use inside the Unity Editor.
This Player class has a member variable called "Stats" which is a struct.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlayerStats Stats;
}
```

Below you can see the System.Serializable struct I am using as "data class"

```
[System.Serializable]
public struct PlayerStats
{
   public uint Speed;

   public void SetSpeed(uint speed)
   {
      this.Speed = Math.clamp(speed, Rules.MinSpeed, Rules.MaxSpeed);
   }
}
```

So later on to prevent the **overhead** i am experiencing from serializing a MonoBehaviour i use

```
JsonUtility.ToJson(player.Stats)
```

Now my question is, if I use SetSpeed anywhere in the code to modify the Value inside the struct

```
player.Stats.SetSpeed(3);
```

does this now lead to copies of the struct being made, because the value is being modified?

Any clarifications would be great.

Comment: For the performance of the serializer it makes no difference if you declare it as `public class PlayerStats { ... }` or `public struct PlayerStates{ ... }`

Comment: On the saving (JSON generation) side it has no performance impact. But when loading it has to create either structs or classes and there i would say it starts to stack up.

Comment: Well this depends of course a lot on the amount but in general it doesn't really make a difference if creating a struct or class instance and deserialize the values into it. It is more a question if heap vs stack memory and whether you pass this to a lot of methods. Generally spoken a class is often the better option but it depends on the exact use case of course ;) it doesn't have to be a `MonoBehaviour` just use a simple class and you wouldn't have to ask this question at all ;)

Comment: I followed the statistics/metrics given by this post  https://medium.com/csharp-architects/whats-faster-in-c-a-struct-or-a-class-99e4761a7b76. It claims instantiating structs is 8.6 times faster than a class. Since im also saving all pathfinding nodes (custom pathfinding) there will be a lot of objects to save, up to 1 million. So this makes a difference for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, changing the value of field in a struct does not cause a copy to be made. The copies are made when the structure is assigned to another variable. SetSpeed is a member function and has no struct parameter so won't cause a copy to be made.

For example, you call a method here:

`JsonUtility.ToJson(playerDTO.Stats);`

This will cause a copy of the structure to be made and assigned to the parameter inside the function, regardless of whether you later call SetSpeed. Any changes you make to `playerDTO` after this call won't change the local copy inside the ToJson function.

Perhaps in your case this isn't a concern (as in many cases). In other cases people could use a struct when actually they want to pass something by reference, in which case they would not get the behaviour they desire.

Just as an example for better understanding

```
// obviously creates a new Stats instance
player.Stats = new Stats();

// only changes the value inside the instance - no copy
player.Stats.Speed = 3;

// A new copy
var states = player.Stats;

// Creates and passes a COPY to the method 
JsonUtility.ToJson(player.Stats)

// again no copy
player.Stats.SetSpeed(3);
```

And just for providing one example for a well known `struct` type ;)

```
// stores a COPY 
var position = transform.position;

// only changes a value - no copy
position.x = 4;

// normalizes the instance itself - no copy
position.Normalize();

// Assigns a COPY
transform.position = position;
```

Comment: I just felt so free to add some code examples for better understanding, hope that is ok with you :)